# why Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] Android Studio?

Tags: android

I am trying to test my app on SDK 17 . Android studio error Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] Here is my android manifest:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.exams"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile project(':library')
}
```

Comment: it seems your application is already installed with greater versionCode 1, either uninstall app from your device your put versionCode greater then installed app on your device.

Comment: What is Android version on your phone/emulator?

Comment: Works..!! I have resolved this issue. Just changed minSdkVersion 17 to minSdkVersion 15 and it runs smoothly.. Thanks for support.